# GIT permission denies(publickey) when running from python subprocess

Tags: git, python-2.7

I have the following piece of Python code:

```
import subprocess
import os

repo_dir = 'C:\dev\codeRepo'
os.chdir(repo_dir)

process = subprocess.Popen("git pull", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
```

I get the following error:

> Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Note, I have public key setup on the server, and I can do "git pull" from Windows command line without having to enter any pass key, and it works. But, from Python program I get this error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause.

Initially I had the git setup such a way that on each git pull it was asking for pass key. In order to stop this, I removed existing key, and added a new one without password (there are other ways of doing it). Since I did not reboot the machine this change was not picked up by the windows system. After a reboot, I got it working.